# How to keep files displaying NULL to a separate folder?

Tags: bash

I have over 10000 files in folder. I was using an rscript to preprocess the files. "It displayed an error

```
"Error in read.table(wd, comment.char ="#", header=T, sep='\t'):
empty beginning of file"
```

. When I opened the file in a text editor the file was empty but the size of the file was around 4 mb. Next, I opened the file in a Notepad++, I was able to see the content as `NULL NULL NULL......NULL`
[image]

I want to keep these kind of files from the folder to another folder. How can I accomplish this. Any help appreciated.!!

Thanks

Comment: Let's first try to understand the content of these files: what do you see if you type `head -c 25 FILE | cat -A` in a terminal (replace `FILE` by the name of one of these files)?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet it shows ```^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@```
I want to identify non-text files and move them into another folder

Comment: This is binary data, not text. If you really want to examine such files use a hex editor, or at least `hexdump`. Check [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/208980/217334) for a possible solution using the `file` command. The specific answer I linked tests the mime-type (more predictable) instead of relying on other magic strings like many other approaches seen around the internet seem to be doing.

Comment: I find your question unclear: Do you want to identifiy files, which (1) consist only of NUL bytes, or (2) start with a series of NUL bytes, or (3) have at least one NUL byte somewhere in them?

Comment: @svp OK, that's a binary file. And what do you see with `od -N10 -tx1 FILE`?

Comment: @RenaudPacalet : ```0000000 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 
0000012```

Comment: @svp OK, your undesirable files start with `NUL` bytes. See my answer to understand how to use the `find` utility to detect and move them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think one potential option could be:

```
# create a file of NULLs
echo -ne '\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0\0' > test.txt

cat -A test.txt
^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@^@

cat test.txt | hexdump -C
00000000  00 00 00 00 00 00 00 00  00 00 00 00 00           |.............|
0000000d

mkdir -p null_files; for f in *.txt; do if [ -z "$(cat $f)" ]; then mv "$f" null_files/; fi; done
-bash: warning: command substitution: ignored null byte in input

ls null_files/
test.txt
```

This only moved the 'test.txt' file and left all of the 'non-NULL' files in place on my system, but obviously it would be a good idea to test it before use, e.g.

```
for f in *.txt; do if [ -z "$(cat $f)" ]; then echo "$f"; fi; done
```

Answer (score 1):

I once had a similar problem with a file that was not displaying correctly. I found that the problem was due to the file encoding. The file was encoded in a different encoding than my computer was expecting, which caused the file to display incorrectly. To fix the problem, I opened the file in a text editor and changed the encoding to the correct encoding. Once I did that, the file displayed correctly.

Hope this helps you!

Comment: I have tried changing the encoding and I got the files with numerous spaces. But, my question is different, I want to identify these kinds of files from bulk files and move them to separate directory

Answer (score 0):

Apparently your *strange* files start with a bunch of zero bytes (`NUL` bytes). If none of the files you want to keep start with a `NUL` byte you can use `find` to identify the files that start with `NUL` and move them away (replace `DESTDIR` by the **existing** destination directory:

```
find . -maxdepth 1 -type f -exec bash -c '
[ "$(od -N1 -tx1 -A none "$1")" = " 00" ] && mv "$1" DESTDIR
' _ {} \; -print
```

For each file in the current directory (`. -maxdepth 1 -type f`) the bash script `[ "$(od -N1 -tx1 -A none "$1")" = " 00" ] && mv "$1" DESTDIR` is executed with argument 0 set to `_` and argument one set to the file name (that's what `{}` means with the `-exec` action of `find`). The script uses `od` to get the hexadecimal representation of the first byte in the file (`od -N1 -tx1 -A none "$1"`). If it is  `00` (with a leading space added by `od`) the file is moved to `DESTDIR`. The name of the moved file is also printed.

Answer (score 0):

You can check file type and filter and move the files:

```
#Check file type
for i *.txt; do file $i >> results.txt; done

#Filter non ascii file types
awk '{ if ($2 != "ASCII text") print $1 }' results.txt > others.txt

#Create the folder
mkdir non_ascii

#move the files to non_ascii
while read file; do mv ${file} non_ascii; done < others.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

This is how i would do it.

we can use `file` to find files which are filled with `NULL` character.

I first create some NULL filled files using `fallocate` and copy some other files like plain texts, compiled binaries and scripts.

```
for i in test{1..5} ; do fallocate -l $(( RANDOM % 100 )) ${i} ; done
cp /etc/{passwd,hosts,hostname} /usr/local/bin/myscript /usr/bin/ssh .
```

output of `file *` for these files:

```
hostname: ASCII text
hosts:    ASCII text
myscript: Bourne-Again shell script, ASCII text executable
passwd:   ASCII text
ssh:      ELF 64-bit LSB pie executable, x86-64, version 1 (SYSV), dynamically linked, interpreter /lib64/ld-linux-x86-64.so.2, BuildID[sha1]=f4263d291efb20da6b29991d4eff0e7fbde195ce, for GNU/Linux 3.2.0, stripped
test1:    data
test2:    data
test3:    data
test4:    data
test5:    data
```

if we use `--mime-type` switch for file it is easier to filter files based on their content:

```
hostname: text/plain
hosts:    text/plain
myscript: text/x-shellscript
passwd:   text/plain
ssh:      application/x-pie-executable
test1:    application/octet-stream
test2:    application/octet-stream
test3:    application/octet-stream
test4:    application/octet-stream
test5:    application/octet-stream
```

now we can use `file` with `awk` to filter file names which are NULL filled and copy/move them somewhere else:

```
file --mime-type * \
  | awk  '{if ($NF == "application/octet-stream"){ k=sub(/:/,"") ; print $k}}' \
  | xargs -I% mv % /dest/dir/ -v
```